# web audio API audiocontext close function is undefined in iOS 7 webview

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

I have used AudioContext web audio API and wanted to release all the resources used by AudioContext.

As per the below tutorial I have used close() to release all resources.
[AudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/close). But in iOS 7 it says close function in undefined.

Comment: close() does not work in iOS 8 as well. But it does not throw any error in desktop chrome.

Answer (score 0):

AudioContext.close() is a relatively new addition to WebAudio. It's likely that Safari has not implemented this yet.